# About Jenkins auto package setting with Keychains and Provisioning Profiles Management

Tags: ios, jenkins

During setting Keychains and Provisioning Profiles Management, no matter how much I taped the "Upload" button with no response back. nothing happend. no alert  no tips, just not work.

[image]

**My environment**

- Java 1.8.0
- Jenkins 2.269
- Keychains and Provisioning Profiles Management 1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use brew to install a specific version to solve this problem.
The version I installed is 2.263.4, and i can use Keychains and Provisioning Profiles Management.

Find the corresponding version submission record from git, download it to the local and install it with brew.

```
git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core.git

# 3a3803f22e24bdcd0b01831fc074a9f28773594d is 2.263.4
git checkout 3a3803f22e24bdcd0b01831fc074a9f28773594d

brew install /Users/xxx/homebrew-core/homebrew-core/Formulajenkins-lts.rb
```

Hope it can help you！